# Node Js and Sequalize model to get data from two tables

Tags: node.js, models, sequelize.js

I have a model that will return people to me using node and sequalize. The model looks like this

```
class DbModel implements IModelMaker {

  static _model: IDatabaseModel = null;

  getModel(db: ISequelize): IDatabaseModel {
    if (DbModel._model)
      return DbModel._model;
    const options = helper.getDatabaseDefaultOptions('people');
    const entity: any = {};
    entity['people_id'] = {type: Sequelize.UUID, primaryKey: true, 'defaultValue': Sequelize.UUIDV4};
    entity['sexes_id'] = helper.getForeignKey('sexes_id', sexes.getModel(db));
    entity['marital_states_id'] = helper.getForeignKey('marital_states_id', marital_states.getModel(db));
    entity['employment_states_id'] = helper.getForeignKey('employment_states_id', employment_states.getModel(db));
    entity['linkedins_id'] = helper.getForeignKey('linkedins_id', linkedins.getModel(db));
    entity['facebooks_id'] = helper.getForeignKey('facebooks_id', facebooks.getModel(db));
    entity['first_names'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['surnames'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['name_to_call_user'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['id_number'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['passport_number'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['birth_date'] = Sequelize.DATEONLY;
    entity['tax_number'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['vat_number'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['message_to_show_on_user_invoice'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['workplace_name'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['is_verified'] = Sequelize.BOOLEAN;
    entity['has_private_profile_enabled'] = Sequelize.BOOLEAN;
    entity['mobile_phone'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['occupations_id'] = Sequelize.UUID;
    entity['profile_photo_url'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['private_profile_url'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['public_profile_url'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['description'] = Sequelize.TEXT;
    entity['created_at'] = Sequelize.DATE;
    const result = db.define('dbo.people', entity, options);
    result.belongsTo(sexes.getModel(db), {foreignKey: 'sexes_id'});
    result.belongsTo(marital_states.getModel(db), {foreignKey: 'marital_states_id'});
    result.belongsTo(employment_states.getModel(db), {foreignKey: 'employment_states_id'});
    result.belongsTo(linkedins.getModel(db), {foreignKey: 'linkedins_id'});
    result.belongsTo(facebooks.getModel(db), {foreignKey: 'facebooks_id'});
    DbModel._model = result;
    return result;
  }
```

This gets me the results that are stored in the dbo.people table which is great because that is what I want and this model works perfectly for that. 
Now what I want to do is to add to this model and call data from another table. So I want to get the data from `dbo.users_references` to be called with this model.

My question is, is there a way to add a join statement to a model that is created like the one above, or will I need to make a new model and call that as a separate function. The second way will work in my case, but I want to keep it simple, so if I can get it all in one model, then I would be happy, else I must just be mildly happy with the other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `define` a model for `users_references` and associate it in the same way as you are doing with `sexes`, `marital_states`, etc. The join will actually occur at query time when specify what to `include`.

Usage example:

```
DbModel.findAll({
  where: ...,
  include: [
    { model: employment_states.getModel(db) },
    { model: users_references.getModel(db) }
  ]
});
```

I apologize if this seems a little hand-wavy - it is, since I gather there's a lot of helper logic in you project that's not in the post. You might want to review [the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/), but admittedly they're a little hazy on how to actually get the data from related tables in the queries, but they should cover enough for what you've described.